# A way to test for a file upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload, file

I'm writing a script to handle a file upload. I've got the script in place, validating and uploading correctly.

But....the upload is optional. When I submit the form, the $_FILES['field_name'] is always present which consequently forces my validation to kick in.

How can I detect if there is a file upload or not?

Comment: The reason why you have value is because the browser send the value of *all* form elements: if empty, it will still send empty value. You can "solve" this by simple JavaScript that upon submit will remove empty elements from the form, let me know if you're interested.

Comment: *(related)* [Unit-Testing File Uploads with PHP](http://qafoo.com/blog/013_testing_file_uploads_with_php.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use :

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
}
```

Which amounts to (almost) the same as the other answers on here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`is_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php).

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
   echo "File ". $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] != '') {

Where 'file' is the name of your file field.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] != '') {
// Code goes here
}
```